# Windows RT - synchronous usage of StorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, storagefile

I want to write a Win8 app, there I use a `Configuration`-class with a `static` member, which is loaded once at startup and can be accessed from everywhere at runtime.

So, the main problem is, the default settings are stored within an xml file, but reading file content is asynchronous (`StorageFile`), but I do not find any solution to wait, until the file is completely loaded, because it is not possible to use `await` in every situation (main thread, constructors), what looks to me like a design issue.
If the file isn't read completely before the `Configuration` data is accessed, there will be incorrect behaviors for this app.

here is an example code:

```
public class Configuration
{
    // stores the only instance of this class
    private Configuration instance = null;

    // public access to the instance
    public Configuration Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Configuration();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Configuration()
    {
        // load data from file synchronously
        // so it is loaded once on first access
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, how to solve this problem, probably I need to change the design of my `Configuration`-class. Any suggestions/hints would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a design decision not to allow any synchronous calls that could take longer than 50 ms, i.e. any file or network IO calls, to make applications more responsive.

Although you can't `await` asynchronous calls from a constructor, nothing is stopping you from firing such calls without waiting for them to complete:

```
private Configuration()
{
    Init();
}

private async void Init()
{
    var contents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}
```

You can then set `Configuration` properties from inside `Init()`. If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can bind the values to UI before they are loaded and the UI will refresh once they are.

If you need to check or wait for the operation to complete at some point in your app you can change the signature of `Init()` to return `Task`:

```
private Configuration()
{
    InitTask = Init();
}

private async Task Init()
{
    var contents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}

public Task InitTask { get; private set; }
```

Now you can check whether it is completed:

```
if (Configuration.Current.IsCompleted)
{
    //
}
```

or even `await` it (this will complete immediately if `Task` has already completed):

```
await Configuration.Current.InitTask;
```

EDIT:

If it doesn't make sense to display anything to the user until the said file is loaded, you could modify your entry page to have to alternative "views":

- actual view (you want the user to see when the app is ready)
- splash screen view (displaying a progress indicator for example)

You could make the right one visible based on `IsCompleted` property which you should expose on your viewmodel with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

You could then design your page as follows:

```
<Page xmlns:common="using:MyApp.Common">
    <Page.Resources>
        <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding Configuration.IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}">
            <!-- put your actual view here -->
        </Grid>
        <Grid Visibility="{Binding Configuration.IsNotCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}">
            <!-- put your splash screen view here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried to use INotifyPropertyChanged, but I doesn't help here in my opinion. It doesn't make any sense to show any page of my app, before this file is loaded. Maybe it is possible to load the file, while the splash screen shows up, and when the file is loaded, the splash screen disappears? Any tips, wether that is possible?

Comment: @FrecherxDachs I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I will do it the way you discribed. The file is pretty small, so a progress bar isn't needed, but without your adjustment, sometimes it led to buggy behavior, because of race conditions. Thanks alot, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another class to store settings - there is `AplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` dictionary provided for every Windows 8 application which is loaded automatically every time the app is launched and you read it without `await` keyword - for example:

```
var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
settings.Values["MyIndex"] = 2;

object value = settings.Values["MyIndex"];
if (value != null)
{
     int myIndex = (int)value;
     //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for this mistake, already I use ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings to store my settings. In the example I wrote above, I wanted say, this is my default configuration for this app (static data/strings, which are constant and will never change, only if I update this app). :: I changed the name of the example class to Configuration, to make it more clearly.

Comment: @FrecherxDachs - Update your question if you are already are using it.

Comment: the usage of ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings wasn't my point, it's just about how to load data from file and fill the properties of a static class on startup